# Converter string para inteiro MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Qual comando eu posso usar para converter string para inteiro no mysql? por exemplo:

Estou fazendo a seguinte relação de tabelas:

```
SELECT mov . * , prod.produto, prod.unidade, prod.icms, prod.ipi, prod.codigo
FROM movimentacao AS mov, produtos AS prod
WHERE mov.Codigo = prod.codigo
```

O campo `prod.codigo` está com o valor `0259` e o campo `mov.Codigo` está com `259` e na hora da comparação eles não são iguais, eu queria saber se tem algum comando que converta o valor do `prod.codigo` para **inteiro** para ficar `259`

Comment: Interessante que não consegui reproduzir aqui o problema, pois comparando string com numérico da forma que você descreveu, o resultado foi True. Que versão de MySQL e engine de DB estão sendo usados?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `CAST()`:

```
SELECT mov . * , prod.produto, prod.unidade, prod.icms, prod.ipi, cast(prod.codigo as unsigned integer)
FROM movimentacao AS mov, produtos AS prod
WHERE mov.Codigo = prod.codigo
```

Fonte: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Answer (score 3):

Basta forçar uma operação numérica na string:

```
SELECT mov.* , prod.produto, prod.unidade, prod.icms, prod.ipi, cast(prod.codigo as unsigned integer)
FROM movimentacao AS mov, produtos AS prod
WHERE mov.Codigo = 0 + prod.codigo
```

Answer (score 3):

***Dessa forma se não tiver nenhum erro de digitação***

Função: [Cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

```
SELECT mov.* , 
       prod.produto, 
       prod.unidade, 
       prod.icms, 
       prod.ipi, 
       prod.prodcodigo
FROM movimentacao AS mov, 
     (
        SELECT CAST(prod.codigo) as prodcodigo,
            prod.produto, 
            prod.unidade, 
            prod.icms, 
            prod.ipi
     ) AS prod
WHERE mov.Codigo = prod.prodcodigo
```

***Obs:*** `prod.codigo` ficou `prod.prodcodigo` pra diferenciar de `mov.codigo`

*Referências:*

- [MySQL - The world's most popular open source database](http://dev.mysql.com/)
- [12.10 Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)